# printf not printing value of a character array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, stack

The `printf` statement within the `pop` function isn't printing anything except a blank character (space). I tried to print the indexes of the array passed in the `pop` function but the same thing is happening. I can't seem to figure out why, can someone please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char stack[400] = "";
int top = -1;

void push(char arr[], int *top, char val) {
    *top = *top + 1;
    arr[*top] = val;
    //printf("%d", *top);
} 

char pop(char arr[], int *top) {
    char temp;
    printf("\n%s\n", arr[0]);
    temp = arr[*top];
    *top = *top - 1;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    push(stack, &top, 'a');
    push(stack, &top, 'b');
    push(stack, &top, 'c');
    //printf("%s", stack);
    pop(stack, &top);
    //printf("\n%s", *val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use %c instead of %s to print the character

Comment: Your compiler should tell you about parameter type mismatch for format specifier `%s`. If you did not get any warning, turn up warning level. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantiv`. If you got such a message, don't just ignore it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print individual stack elements, you can use `%d` or `%c` like this:

```
char val = pop(stack, &top);
printf("stack top was %c (ASCII %d)\n", val, val);
```

If you want to print the whole stack as a string, you can use:

```
printf("stack: %.*s\n", top + 1, stack);
```

Note that since `stack` and `top` are passed as arguments, there is no need to make them global variables.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACK_DEPTH  400

void push(char arr[], int *top, char val) {
    if (top < STACK_DEPTH - 1) {
        *top = *top + 1;
        arr[*top] = val;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "stack full for '%c'\n", val);
    }
} 

char pop(char arr[], int *top) {
    if (top >= 0) {
        char temp = arr[*top];
        *top = *top - 1;
        return temp;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "stack empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char stack[STACK_DEPTH] = "";
    int top = -1;

    push(stack, &top, 'a');
    push(stack, &top, 'b');
    push(stack, &top, 'c');
    printf("stack contents: %.*s\n", top + 1, stack);

    char val = pop(stack, &top);
    printf("stack top was %c (ASCII %d)\n", val, val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah i was planning for that but the global declaration was a requirement by our subject teacher

Answer (score 1):

Your program crashes with a segmentation fault.  It's because you use `%s` (for char *) while passing in a character `arg[0]`.   Use `%c` instead:

```
printf("\n%c\n",arr[0]);
```

Comment: ok sorry for the delay

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about just reminding you as a relatively new user on here.